# "RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted" with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Tensorflow/Keras model I downloaded from the Internet to do hand gesture recognition. The program works perfectly on 2 out of 3 tested PCs (1 MAC 1 PC actually), but it just crashes on the 3rd PC. We have the exact same code, the same model and the same Python, Keras and Tensorflow versions. The error message I get is this:

```
C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py:115: RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted
  metadata.ParseFromString(file_content)
```

I understand it seems to come from this piece of code right here:

```
handGestureModel = load_model('hand_gesture_dataset')
```

However, I have no clue why the model loading would work perfectly on 2 computers and then just straight up crash on the third one. Any help?